# How can I know when my Fragment is ready to be viewed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, race-condition

I have a Fragment that is being attached with an animation like so:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

I have two concerns.

1) That the Fragment won't be fully rendered before the animation begins (there's some reasonably convoluted stuff that happens in the fragment, including, possibly, an HTTP call that fetches the data necessary to draw.

2) Within the fragment there are additional animations that I don't want to start until I'm sure that the user is actually looking at them.

I suspect that the best way to handle (1) is to just not call `commit()` until the Fragment reports that it has finished assembling all its parts, but for (2) I can't see a way to know that it is definitely attached to the Activity and rendering (so that it's safe to start the animations inside the Fragment).

So, I guess my question is... is commit() a blocking call? Can I be sure that on the next line (or at the end of the Fragment transition animation) the Fragment is rendered and it's safe to start animating?  Or should I use an animation listener on the Transition and tell the fragment to start its internal animations after the Transition animation has completed?

Answer (score 0):

For 1) Your strategy is correct. Setup some kind of call into the Fragment where it can tell you it has done the background work it needs to do to setup. Alternatively you can do that outside the fragment and pass that data in as part of the fragment construction.

For 2) commit() is not a blocking call, it is a "throw this on the scheduler" call. You may be able to use [onActivityCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) to know that the fragment is created and attached to the window properly. When I have done similar things in the past, I have added a delayed animation in that method that fires after the fragment manager transition delay has passed to begin the animations in the fragment.